# DataGrid Loading/Saving XML

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net, visual-studio, datagrid

I have a rather straightforward question.

How to I get a DataGrid in WPF to save/load raw XML files and have the ability to display/edit them with other controls? The application will only work offline so I won't need SQL. Just simply open, edit and save data to XML.

My previous projects with WinForms involved creating a DataSet (xsd file) and a DataTable, bound it to a DataGridView. Then add new items with by calling "AddDataTableRow()". Save/Read XML files by "ReadXML", "WriteXML".

I'm kinda new to WPF so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Use Linq and XElement instead of an Xdocument and data sets. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669141.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward approach would be to simply define a data collection class (an ObservableCollection containing instances of a data class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged), mark these classes as serializable and use XmlSerializer for serializing/deserializing.

A sample data class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and the data collection class:

```
[Serializable]
public class PersonCollection : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
}
```

Some XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PersonCollection x:Key="PersonCollection"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PersonCollectionViewSource" Source="{StaticResource PersonCollection}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonCollectionViewSource}}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="Save" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And class MainWindow with the deseralization code in the constructor and the serialization code in the button click handler:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PersonCollection persons;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        persons = (PersonCollection)Resources["PersonCollection"];

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonCollection));

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("Persons.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> personData = (IEnumerable<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

            foreach (Person p in personData)
            {
                persons.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonCollection));

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("Persons.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, persons);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it produces a few errors. ('local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 6, position 10.' XML is not valid.) and (The name 'persons' does not exist in the current context). After converting the code to VB these errors still remained.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i left that out. "local" is only a XAML namespace declaration for the namespace that the PersonCollection class resides in, "DataGridTest" in my example. "persons" is a member variable of the MainWindow class. I've edited the XAML code sample. Replace "DataGridTest" with the namespace of your project.

Comment: All my original code was VB and I use this converter [http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb]. I figured out most of the errors but I can't seem to get the app running. I've uploaded all the testing source code here [http://www.mediafire.com/?1wmzeiptct2ujfd]. I'm learning C# at the moment but the thing is thousands of lines of code are already in VB and migrating from one language to an other would be a hassle.

Comment: Get the complete sample C# project [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14518717/DataGridTest.zip).

Comment: The code works fine. Worked out almost everything. Just one last question. How do I edit a DataGridItem by a TextBox for example. I figured out how to get the selected item by using DirectCast. Can't seem to get the editing worked though.

Comment: You mean selecting a row and display/edit the selected item in another (TextBox) control?

Comment: Yes, select an item, display it's data in a textbox (FirstName and LastName in separate textboxes) and on the TextChanged event edit the items in the selected row.

Comment: You can simply bind the TextBoxes to the same CollectionViewSource as the DataGrid, since the CollectionViewSource supports the [Master-Detail Binding Scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#master_detail_scenario). You also have to set the Path property in each TextBox binding. I've uploaded an extended example project [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14518717/DataGridTest.zip) with two data-bound TextBoxes. Now you can upvote my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Here's my picture of my WinForms project [http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/21292593.png/]. In a word, you select a row, click a button, a new form comes up, you edit the information, click another button to apply changes to the datagrid or to cancel them.
P.S. I can't vote yet, need to get 15 rep but I will when I can, you've been a great help.

Comment: That should be fairly easy by simply overwriting the existing (i.e. edited) Person object in the PersonCollection. Removing the old and adding a new object would make the DataGrid loose the selected row, but setting the properties of the existing object will work because Person implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Any idea how to set the properties of the existing object in code?

Comment: You can access the _persons_ collection, e.g. persons[0].FirstName = "Bart";